# Getting points from a .txt file and plotting them in a picturebox in C#

Tags: c#, user-interface, plot, infinite-loop

I'm trying to build a windows form application in which I read a comma separated list from a .txt file and then plot that using the DrawLine function. My code keeps getting stuck in an infinite loop and I'm not sure how I should proceed further. I have no preference of how I should plot it and the only reason I'm using the drawline function is because I don't know of any other way so I'm open to any other ideas that might be better suited to doing this task.

```
       private void startToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        StreamReader sr = new StreamReader("../../sample.txt");
        string[] values = null;
        zee1 = sr.ReadLine();
        while (zee1 != null)
        {
            values = zee1.Split(',');
            x1 = Int32.Parse(values[0]);
            x2 = Int32.Parse(values[1]);
            y1 = Int32.Parse(values[2]);
        }



        //BackGroundBitmap.Save("result.jpg"); //test if ok
        Point point1 = new Point(int.Parse(values[0]), int.Parse(values[2]));
        Point point2 = new Point(int.Parse(values[1]), int.Parse(values[2]));

        pictureBox1.Enabled = true;
        g = pictureBox1.CreateGraphics();
        g.DrawLine(pen1, point1, point2);
    }
```

Please note I'm trying to plot two different values of x on the same plot for the same values of y. Also that values[0] is an array that contains all the data in the first column of the .txt file and so forth for values[1] and values[2].

The txt file I'm using is as follows

> 0,4,0
>
> 1,2,1
>
> 2,1,2
>
> 3,6,3
>
> 4,1,4
>
> 5,3,5
>
> 6,8,6

Answer (score 0):

You're in an infinite `while` loop because the condition never changes. You need to update `zee1`. The most popular way to do this is to simply update it *in* the condition:

```
while ((zee1 = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
{
    // what was here already
}
```

It also seems as if you want to draw a set of line segments (I assume one to the next), so you could do that like so:

```
private void startToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    List<Point> points = new List<Point>();
    using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader("../../sample.txt"))
    {
        string[] values = null;
        while ((zee1 = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
        {
            values = zee1.Split(',');
            points.Add(new Point(int.Parse(values[0]), int.Parse(values[2])));
        }
    }

    pictureBox1.Enabled = true;
    g = pictureBox1.CreateGraphics();
    for (int i = 0; i < points.Count - 1; i++)
        g.DrawLine(pen1, points[i], points[i+1]);
}
```

Comment: After a little bit more research isn't it better to use the chart tool? Could you please explain a little bit about how to use that tool because I have no idea and as you can probably tell I just started coding. Thanks! Any code is appreciated

Comment: @AbdullahNawaz I have no idea what chart tool you're talking about.